# Interactive public iPython Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, interactive

I have an ipython notebook that has interactive, dynamic content such as dropdowns.  Is it possible to publicly display this notebook and have it be interactive online?  I want the notebook to not have to be downloaded and run on a local python kernel but publicly accessible and interactive online.

Comment: "If you want to access your notebook server remotely via a web browser" - https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/public_server.html#notebook-public-server

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterhub does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

A promising direction to pursue is [temporary, disposable notebooks](https://github.com/jupyter/tmpnb):

> tmpnb launches a docker container for each user that requests one. In practice, this gets used to provide temporary notebooks, demo the IPython notebook as part of a Nature article, or even provide Jupyter kernels for publications.

Source: [Deploying JupyterHub for Education](https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/deploying-jupyterhub-for-education/)